# Help finding turning points to plot quartic and cubic functions

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

My teacher assigned us some graphing homework. I know how to graph all of them manually all except these two

1. $f_1(x)=x^4-x^3-4x^2$
2. $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^3+2x^2-8x-2$

When i asked him how he said it was above our grade level and it was a calculus question so we should just use graphing calculators. So since I'm still curious, I'm asking here. Detailed answers with steps would be nice. The main thing I need to know is how to find the exact location of turning points.

Comment: Your homework is just to enter some functions into a graphing calculator and copy the plot onto paper? What's the educational value in that?

Comment: Absolutely 0... hence the reason I am here :)

Comment: Your question implies that you are studying pre-calculus math. What tools have you learned (rational root theorem, etc.)?

Comment: Doesnt sound familiar but its 1am so that doesnt mean much :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just take $f_1(x) = x^4-x^3-4x^2 = x^2\ (x^2 - x - 4)$.  Start by finding the roots (the values of $x$ where $f_1(x) = 0$).  A quartic equation may have up to four real roots.  From the $x^2$ factor, we see that two of them are $x = 0$ and $x = 0$ — a "double" root.

What about the other two roots?  To solve $x^2 - x - 4 = 0$, we can use the quadratic equation:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2} $$

So, $y = x^2 - x - 4$ would describe a parabola that crosses the $x$-axis at -1.562… and 2.562….  It is centered at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ (the midpoint between the roots), with a minimum at (0.5, -4.25).

Now let's consider what happens when we multiply that by $x^2$.  That turns the parabola into a lopsided W-like curve (but smoother than a W), shifted to the right of the origin, and touching the $x$-axis at -1.562…, 0, 0, and 2.562….

---

To find interesting points such as the minima and inflection points, though, you would need calculus.  To give you a taste of what you haven't learned… we take the first derivative ("$\frac{d}{dx}\ f_1(x)$"), which tells you the slope of the curve for any $x$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ f_1(x) = 4x^3 - 3x^2 - 4 \cdot 2 \cdot x = \frac{x}{16} (8x - (3 - \sqrt{137}))(8x - (3 + \sqrt{137}))$$

We find that the slope is 0 at $x = 0$, $x \approx -1.088$, and $x \approx 1.838$.  We conclude that $f_1(x)$ has a local maximum at (0, 0), a local minimum at (-1.088, -2.0458), and a local minimum at (1.838, -8.3097).

To find the inflection points, we would take the derivative of the derivative.  This second derivative is

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ f_1(x) = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot x^2 - 3 \cdot 2 \cdot x - 8 = \frac{1}{12} (12x - (3 - \sqrt{105}))(12x - (3 + \sqrt{105}))$$

The inflection points, where the second derivative is zero, are at $x \approx -0.604$ and $x \approx 1.104$.  That is, $f_1(x)$ is $\cap$-shaped in the interval $\frac{3-\sqrt{105}}{12} \lt x \lt \frac{3+\sqrt{105}}{12}$, and $\cup$-shaped everywhere else.

All of the information above can be seen in the plot.  The roots are the red points, the extrema are green, and the inflection points are purple.

[image: Plot of x^4 - x^3 - 4x^2]

Comment: Lol I just figured it out before you posted this XD still thanks for the EXTREMELY detailed answer. It is appreciated. :)

Comment: Oh the check mark. NP :) sorry first time on this forum still getting used to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the calculus classes you would be introduced to differentiation and next you will know how to use those derivatives to get turning points.

Chart out your road at first by calculating and plotting on a graph. *Then and next*  later on you will appreciate those techniques of turning.

Comment: Could you give me a brief explanation of how to do these or one of these problems? I would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: I can do the reaserch myself if you could just write out the steps. Im not asking for a full lecture and for you to teach me everything. Just work out one of the problems and i can take it from there. I would really appriciate it since im interested.

Comment: @Davsmith4 You should be patient, right now do not seek shortcuts.Go through https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/derivative_intro/v/calculus-derivatives-1

Comment: im not even required to show work so i wouldnt call it a shortcut. I just do better learning if i can see a real world example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this can be of any use to you, but for what it's worth: Turning points of graphs come from places where the derivative is zero, because the derivative of the function gives the slope of the tangent line. In calculus you would learn to compute the first derivative here as $4x^3-3x^2-8x$, so you'd find its zeroes and then check in any of several ways which of them give turning points.

Comment: Very helpful thanks :) For the record it really isnt of use im just interested.

Comment: So i now see how the derivative works to find the location of a turning point. If you can could you give me an explanation of how you came about finding that derivative?

Comment: The derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$, the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives, and derivatives don't see constant multiples.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for the explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are so enthusiastic, I give just one step of differentiation.
$$ f(x) = x^4 -x^3 -4 x^2 $$

$$ f'(x) = 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 - 8 x = 0, i.e.,  x\, ( 4 x^2 - 3 x -8 ) = 0 $$

It gives one root x = 0 at origin and  you get two more roots after solving above quadratic.

Comment: Thank you good sir :) I understand i wont need this for awhile but I enjoy it so thanks :) I i could bother you for one last exploitation. Now that i know the point where the turn takes place on the x axis, by say of the derivitive, how do i find it on the y axis?

Comment: lol nvm just remembered... i feel like a moron now. guess i shouldnt try to think this late at night :P i cant thank you enough for taking the time to explain but ill try. THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @Davsmith4 Right :)) for kicks.. The graph of $f_1(x)$ shows you should n't be thinking or posting around such an hour. Take a nap and it shoots up again.